# Same error message at end of every update run

Tags: apt, updates, error-handling

Each and every time that I run update, the last 4 lines read as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fCA
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

What can or must I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My quick and dirty fix is:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fCA
```

Then `sudo apt-get install` works again!

---

But after `sudo apt-get update`, the same problem may **RISE AGAIN**!